# How to print only once the items in a list (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm a beginner at Python and I've made a code that prints a list of products that the user entered, but whenever I print it, it doesn't break when it reaches the last element...
EDIT: The string is supposed to be with no spaces. ex: Cottage,Cheese,Bacon
Here's my code:

```
def menu():
    print "1. View products"
def view(products):
    print products
def main():
    str1 = raw_input("")
    products =str1.split(',')
    menu()
    choice = input("")
    while (choice != 0):
        if(choice == 1):
            view(products)
main()
```

Comment: you never change choice inside the while loop, so the loop keeps on running

Comment: You don't update the choice inside the while loop, and it is always running with the first choice. Put `choice = input("")` at the end of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an infinite loop which is why the list keeps getting printed. You need to ask for input more than once otherwise the loop will never end

```
choice = None
while (choice != 0) and (choice != 1):
    if(choice == 1):
        view(products)
    choice = input("Type 1 to view products, 0 to quit: ")
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this code won't work. Setting choice to 1 before while loop, cause that you will never enter to while loop.

Answer (score 1):

In this code you only prints list, and while in this case generates infinite loop.
In your example products is a list. So why you wouldn't pass it to view function, and then pass it to for loop to print content of products